# Review my usage of NoIndex and rel=canonical

Tags: seo, noindex, rel-canonical, canonical-url

I am working with my developer to redesign my image macro (meme) generator website. I am concerned about semi-duplicate and paginated pages appearing in the search index and would appreciate your views on whether the following usage is correct.

The site creates pages such as newest memes, trending memes, top voted memes etc whcih are paginated but obviously link to different images (links) Each category/section has about 2,500 of these pages each containing about 25 images. I have modified titles and meta descriptions to avoid duplicates eg. Newest memes page 2 etc. But on the current site all these subpages appear on the index which looks messy, and I don't find much reason the SE will point users to newest memes page 6 for example.

For these I am contrmplating using for all pages after page 1 so that only Newest memes will appear in the index (page 1) but links to individual images will be crawled by the search engines.

Another issue is that for the individual meme or character (template page) the upper half of the page always remains the same with the most functionality, but we have added a "related images" module to these pages with pagination for user experience. The issue now is that the site has originalmemelink/2, original memelink/3 etc for many pages and the same for character(template page) Since these pages will essentially be duplicates except the related memes module I was considering adding where the canonical url points to the main (first) page for the meme or character page.

All pagination is loaded via javasript when the user clicks on a page number but the actual link to the page URL is not displayed in pagination. It only appears in browser after the user clicks on the page.

My question is this: Is my current usage appropriate for the categories pages and the indicidual pages? Would it be better to also apply Noindex to the individual meme and template pages after page 1 or is the canonical better as they contain almost duplicate content? Will using the canonical tag still allow these subpages to be indexed or divert link juice from the main meme or trmplate page? Are there any negative effects in terms of SEO caused by such an implementation? I look forward to your responses.

Kind Regards

Comment: We don't do website reviews here.   If you need additional answers to this question please rephrase the title to describe how you are using them in such a way that others with a similar issue can also find the answer

Answer (score 1):

As far as Google's position is concerned, they have clearly stated that noindex and canonical shouldn't be applied together. 
[Source](https://www.seroundtable.com/noindex-canonical-google-18274.html)

If you have paginated content use canonical, if you have content in two forms say full version and lite version ( as found in forums) , use `canonical`. If you have thin content say member pages you may not want to index them use `noindex`

Comment: Hi, thank you but what of the paginated content varies between pages. Canonical provides a preferred page for duplicate content and I can apply it to certain sectiobs. But if the content varies wouldn't NoIndex be a better choice for pages after the forst?

Comment: Paginated content is supposed to vary between pages. As long as you have individual content set to index you shouldn't worry.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I don;t quite understand what you mean. For some category pages the content varies between paginated content, but for the SEs if you want only the first page of the paginated series to be displayed in SEs, while allowing crawling and following of the other pages to occur, wouldn't it be best to set Noindex for all pages after the 1st. As for the canonical (which will be used on a completely different page) it will be set for 2nd and 3rd pages where the content is not ocmpletely different. The page numberso nly refere to a module within a page which load something ....

Comment: similar to a "related images" widget but for users to see more the url will display as page 2 and page 3. Since the rest of the page remains exactly the same, including the main content above the widget, I was thinking of adding a canonical to those pages. Regards